# Generating Rust executable or library, depending on the target platform

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo, buildconfiguration

I am targeting my Rust project for Windows and Linux.

On Windows, the code needs to be linked to an executable, whereas on Linux - as a shared library.

To link the project as a Linux shared library, I added the following section to `Cargo.toml`:

```
[lib]
name = "my_project_name"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

However that results in shared library generated on Windows, too.

Is there a way to tell Rust compiler to link the project as executable on Windows and as a library on Linux?

Comment: I think it not possible, but you may try to build the binary and the library for both platforms, then using the required ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it's not possible to do so right now. Closest information I could find was [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4881#issuecomment-420373386) for a similar use case.